# what is class don't extent

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Please experts
what this error means and how to solve it?

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: `'SIS_HQ.Login' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.`

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Login " Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="SIS_HQ.Login" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Source File: `/Account/Login.aspx    Line: 1`

thank you

Comment: It means what it says. The class `SIS_HQ.Login` doesn't extend (sub class) `System.Web.UI.Page`. Show us the definition of `SIS_HQ`.

Answer (score 2):

If Login is not already a page, then modify like this:

```
namespace SIS_HQ
{

class Login : System.Web.UI.Page {  ....  }

}
```

If Login is already a page (ie inherits from System.Web.UI.Page), then it's probably a naming conflict - the name Login is probably used elsewhere, so probably easiest to try a different page name - eg Authenticate.aspx